# Wordpress com URL amigáveis - erro no Apache - Como resolver?

Tags: wordpress, apache, url-rewrite

Estou com problemas no Wordpress com URL amigáveis. Simplesmente não funciona mesmo usando o arquivo .htaccess sugerido pelo site de suporte do Wordpress.

```
cat .htaccess 

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Acredito que o erro seja na configuração do `Apache`.
Alguma ideia de como resolver isso ?

Comment: Você está utilizando um servidor local (como wamp, xampp, etc.) ou um servidor online?

Comment: servidor local no MAC OS mas acho que é igual no Linux.

Comment: Encontrei um post que explica bem e [de forma detalhada](http://gustavodutra.com/geek/como-usar-mod_rewrite-de-verdade) mas no meu caso só faltava o `AllowOverride All`.

Answer (score 5):

Verifique no seu arquivo `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` as seguintes condições:

1. A linha abaixo deve estar descomentada

   `LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so`
2. As linhas que definem se o .htaccess poderá ser sobrescrito por definições locais dos conteúdos específicos geralmente vem definida como `AllowOverride  None` você deve alterar para:

   `AllowOverride All`
3. Certifique-se de que se `RewriteEngine` aparecer no arquivo esteja como abaixo:

   `RewriteEngine on`
4. manter no diretório Raiz do site sua configuração de `.htaccess` corretamente descrita na sua pergunta.

That's all.